# How do I convert from dot-separated money into comma-separated number

Tags: java, format, currency, csv

I have the following possible input values that are expressed in an abbreviated way:

- **$39.44**
- **$0.523**
- **$1.336**

Which I would like to convert into:

- **$39,440,000**
- **$523,000**
- **$1,336,000**

I would prefer to use a generic approach rather than building strange strings so I tried to use DecimalFormat(java) object although I am not getting the desired results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have so that people can help you fix it.

Comment: Is the input value in a string?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
String[] values = "$39.44,£0.523,€1.336".split(",");
for (String value : values) {
    char ccy = value.charAt(0);
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(value.substring(1));
    System.out.printf("%s => %s%,d%n", value, ccy, (int)(amount * 1e6));
}
```

prints

```
$39.44 => $39,440,000
£0.523 => £523,000
€1.336 => €1,336,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially all you have to do is replace commas with dots, and dots with commas.

The following code will change "$2,400.25" to "$2.400.25". If you send the dotted currency through this method again, you'll get the comma version back. It's a simple inversion.

```
public class DotsToCommas {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dotCurrency = "$2,400.35";
    String commaCurrency = invertCommasAndDots(dotCurrency);

    System.out.println(commaCurrency);
  }

  public static String invertCommasAndDots(String dotString) {
    StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < dotString.length(); i++) {
      if (dotString.charAt(i) == '.')
        outputBuffer.append(',');
      else if (dotString.charAt(i) == ',')
        outputBuffer.append('.');
      else
        outputBuffer.append(dotString.charAt(i));
    }

    return outputBuffer.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not represent money as a double.  There are values that are valid for money which cannot be represented with a double (or a float)
This appears to be a reasonable technique:

1. Determine how many zeros you want to use as padding.  Store this value.
2. Remove the dollar sign and all periods.  `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.strip(stringName, "$.")` will do this
3. Zero pad fill to the desired size.
4. Format using what ever technique you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions and the math. I came across with this solution:

```
public class convertMillions {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currency = "$";
    char delimiter = ´,´;
    String value = "39.44";   //Example

    String commaCurrency = convert(value, currency, delimiter);
    System.out.println(commaCurrency);
  }


  public String convert(String value, String currency, char delimiter) {

     boolean zeroValue = value.isEmpty();
     if(zeroValue)
       return " ";  //Used when String is empty

     /*Convert into plain String number*/   
     double amount = Double.parseDouble(value.substring(0));
     String numberStr = String.valueOf((int)(amount * 1e6));

     /*Append unit (group separator) delimiter and currency*/
     double number = Double.valueOf(numberStr);
     String pattern = "###,###";
     DecimalFormat formatter;
     DecimalformatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Local.US);
     dfs.setGroupingSeparator(delimiter);

     formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern, dfs);
     String cypher = formatter.format(number);      
     String money = currency.concat(cypher);

     return money;

   }
}
```

**Input:**

- 39.44
- 0.523
- 1.336
- 7
- 125

**Output:**

- $39,440,000
- $523,000
- $1,336,000
- $7,000,000
- $125,000,000